# canActivate as directive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I wonder... if we have defined canActivate in module imports then it would be great if we could use it as directive, right?

Please, take a look on my plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/VbI5Opu3MmGfbco3ok8h?p=preview

you can't run secret-child, but it has anchor to it.

I preapared directive, but I don't have idea how to access to canActivate in specific router. Could you help me please?

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Directive({ selector: '[routerLinkCanActivate]' })
export class RouterLinkCanActivateDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer, router: Router) {
    console.log(router)
  }
}
```